# Capital letter in the word "one"?

Tags: capitalization

Suppose I have a headline for a subsection of a book or article that goes something like: Everything Collected in One Place.

Is this correct or should it be: Everything Collected in one Place. ?

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a matter of style, but it would most often be capitalised.

In titles we generally capitalise all words except articles, coordinating conjunctions, and for most but not all styles, prepositions. Hence:

> Everything Collected in One Place

Notably, in a lot of European languages, there is a lack of distinction between the word *a/an* (an article) and the word *one* (a determiner, specifically a cardinal number, but not an article). This though is not the case with Modern English (it was with Old English), so there can be no confusion on the point.

There are other styles in use. Some would capitalise even prepositions:

> Everything Collected In One Place

Some would not capitalise determiners (including *one*) along with all conjuctions (not just coordinating):

> Everything Collected in one Place

But these are rarer, and besides which, someone using such a style might decide that *one* was important enough in the concept conveyed (that is, that there was just 1 place was important) that they would bend the rule and capitalise it:

> Everything Collected in One Place [again]

There are other title styles in use besides these, which for completeness, might only capitalise nouns:

> Everything collected in one Place

Or else full all-caps, full all-lower and normal sentence case.

> EVERYTHING COLLECTED IN ONE PLACE
>
> everything collected in one place
>
> Everything collected in one place

Unless you've a a style-guide to go for, I would strongly suggest the first style I list here as simple to follow and commonly understood and use. My next-strongest suggestion would be the fourth style, where we lower-case all determiners but title-case them again if they are particularly important to the title in question (which in this example ends up with the same capitalisation as the first style, but might not). The others though are not wrong, they are just different styles.